# lighttpd - redirect everything to https

Tags: redirect, https, lighttpd

I have tried to use the example from this [wiki page](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps) -

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    # capture vhost name with regex conditiona -> %0 in redirect pattern
    # must be the most inner block to the redirect rule
    $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
        url.redirect = (".*" => "https://%0$0")
    }
}
```

But when I enter this url -

```
http://www.domain.co.il/index.php?shop=amazon
```

I got redirected to

```
https://index.php/index.php?shop=amazon
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The example on the wiki page is fine; the question is how you tried to use it - maybe show us a larger part of your config.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine after removing this -

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/min/([a-z]=.*)" => "/min/index.php?$1",
        "^(.*)\.(jpg|gif|woff|tff|png|js|css|html|htm|txt)(.*)$" => "$0",
        "^/question2answer/(.+)$" => "/question2answer/index.php?qa-rewrite=$1",
       "^/$" => "/index.php"
     )
```

Comment: But is there a way to do so with addition redirecting to "www." if there is no "www." in host? May be I need to ask a new question?

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the most elegant way, but it worked for us. Explicitly catches a regex match. (Note: maybe it should be `"https://%1$1"`)

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.*)$" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
    }
}
```

Comment: .* matches by default the complete string (greedy match), and so %0 and $0 are perfectly fine. $SERVER also adds a socket bind, which usually isn't wanted - the scheme matching is the right way.